# How to password-protect a VbaProjectPart using OpenXml SDK

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office, openxml-sdk

I have a scenario where users download their Word document from our local server and when they save that document, instead of saving it locally, the document is sent back to the server using a macro (which is "injected" by the server every time a user downloads a document that doesn't contains the latest version of the macro).

Now that we are going to send this solution to our final tests prior deploying it, we needed to protect that macro, I know I can password protect a macro using Microsoft Office by simply right clicking in the macro project inside the document and selecting "block from viewing" and inserting a password.

However, since the macro must be handled by the server, I need to find a way to protect that macro when I generate it, currently the macro is generated using OpenXml SDK using a VbaProjectPart. I couldn't find anything on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to sign and protect the macro programmatically using Open Xml SDK I decided to download the document, sign it and protect it using word then I used "Open Xml SDK Productivity Tools" to "reverse engineer" the DOCM created and then I copied the binary "VbaProjectPart" created by the tool.

It's not the best way to do it since I need to have a separate documentation for this process and need to do the whole process when the macro changes, however, since the code isn't expected to change anymore I decided to go that way.

Hope this helps anyone who wants to know how to include password protected macros inside an Open Xml document.